# Multiple sessions are created in oracle db by dotnet web application in visual studio 2008 in live server

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, c#-3.0

I have webapplication in vs2008 and database oracle. Where my application make connection to fetch data from database, no session is maintained in oracle database.

but when i deployed my application in web server IIS 6.0 in prodcution. Every request , send by application to database to fetch data create session in oracle database.

Its create multiple sessions in database by application.

anyone help to resolve it and figure out root cause for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if are closing and disposing your connection and command objects. 
Also check your connection pool settings in config file. Is should be on by default. The number of sessions that are initially opened will depend on the pool size.